# iOS push notification to remove delivered notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm working on a app project that uses react-native and FCM Push Notification (rnfirebase 5.6.x).
I send a notification when the user receives some message and I need to remove that delivered notification if the user reads that message on another source (like our web app).

With the app open or in background, I can send another push with some userInfo to let me know what I need to remove.

Everything is working perfect... Except when the user kill the app. Then I have no control on the received notification...

I tried the use the tag prop on the notification data, but according with firebase, it is for Android only.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: If the user force quits the App, there doesn't appear to be anything you can do

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks..
But, how does WhatsApp do that? :/

There must be some witchcraft...

Comment: WhatsApp cheats, a lot